# Append items using jQuery + PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

In the following code I'm calling some images using PHP code.

Note: I used "Advanced Custom Fields" for Wordpress

```
<?php
// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('upload-masonry') ):
 $i = 0;
    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('upload-masonry') ) : the_row('5');
            $i++;
            if( $i > 9 )
            {
                break;
            }
?>             
     <span><img src="<?php the_sub_field('image');?>"></span>          
 <?
    endwhile;
else :
    // no rows found
endif;
?>
```

9 images will show per call, now I want to append 9 more. But since I'm not very good in jQuery, I don't know how to implement that. Has anybody done it before so could help me out with this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("#grid").append("<span><img src='<?php the_sub_field('image');?>'></span>");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put PHP code in your JS script.
On the click on btn2 you need to make an ajax call to a page that contains the 'next set' of images that you want to load. You can them use `.append()` to add them in after the existing images by appending the parent in the dom. On the PHP page that shows the images you can include the next 'next' bt2n which can include a offset parameter to load 'the next set' each time it is clicked.

So reading for you will be...

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Also are you are using Wordpress you maybe able to find a plugin with the feature you are looking for.

Comment: Could you help me out with an example?